# Initializing a structure in c++

Tags: c++

g++ 4.4.3

I have the following structure from a API guide:

```
typedef struct NETWORK_INFO
{
    int network_id;
    int count;
} NETWORK_INFO, *NETWORK_INFO;
```

And in the source code they are doing this:

```
NETWORK_INFO net_info = {};
```

Is the 2 curly braces initializing the object of the structure? But what would it initialize the values to?

Many thanks for any advice,

Comment: You might find this answer to a related question useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775902/zeroing-out-a-struct-in-the-constructor/775935#775935

Comment: This code is illegal. You must use different tokens on the last line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will default-initialize all fields of variable `net_info` - set them both to zero. That's a handy one-liner used to initialize `struct`s that don't have a user-defined constructor instead of using `memset()`.